# USB Compliant Power/Charging Circuit

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, low-power, usb-host

I am designing a device that can charge a USB device, such as a cell phone. I have a 5v DC output source from my device. I know I can just tie D+ and D- together, and connect the 5v to the power pins, but I would really rather not do that, as I want to be as USB compliant as possible. I also understand that many devices won't accept power from a setup as mentioned above.

I am hoping there is an single IC I could use, that can negotiate with the client device, decide on an output power (100ma or 500ma) and supply the power to the device. Basically, it wouldn't be that much different for the client device if it were just plugged in to a computer.

Forgive me for my ignorance, I am not used to dealing with USB, but I would like to know if such an IC exists, or maybe better solutions.

Oh another thing, power is extremely limited, every ma counts, so efficiency is very important.

Answer (score 1):

> I also understand that many devices won't accept power from a setup as
>   mentioned above.

What gave you this understanding? That's how all cell phone chargers work. The main variation is the resistance used to short D+ and D- on the charger end, as Apple uses something other than just a dead short, to make sure their chargers are "special" and thus higher-margin.

If you want to work as a USB host, you will need a microcontroller that can act as a USB host. There are a large number of such microcontrollers, from a variety of vendors. The quality and ease of use of software stacks for the host varies. Personally, If I had to implement a "dumb" USB host, I'd probably use the cheapest AVR 8-bit controller that supports USB hosting, and the LUFA software stack (www.fourwalledcubicle.com) which is easy to work with, and has good support from avr-gcc / avr-libc.

Also, USB 1.1 and USB 2.0 can only negotiate 500 mA of charging current. If you short together D+ and D-, you are advertising yourself as a "dump charger" which means that devices may draw up to 1A. Another useful thing to do is to provide 5.25V, to make sure you compensate for any voltage drop in thin/cheap wiring typically used.